# jQuery works in old DOM after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a page where I some jQuery code for. After it has finished it goes to the next page. 
I use this to go to the next page:

```
$("body").load(//url,function(){
   //do your work
});
```

The pages loads correctly into the old page. With chrome I can see the new DOM.
The function is exactly the same for both pages

```
$('button').each(function() {
   //start working
}
```

Only at the second or even third page it keeps working in the old DOM.
The first and second page are almost exactly the samen just other data they both exists from tables.
As an example I have a table in every page with a random number of rows but I only need the rows where there is a button in, there are no other buttons on the page so I for each button.
When i execute the code everything on the first page goes like it should but at the second page it uses the data from the first page again, so not the new data I loaded.

If I take out the load and  paste the code in console in chrome then there are no problems and everything works like it should. This is no problem if there are only 2 or three pages but if the page count gets bigger it will be a problem..

Comment: Could you rephrase this? Isn't the HTML client side? What are you trying to achieve here? What does not work? What is the old DOM?

Comment: I did my best.
Html is client side yes but it's saved server side.
The functions do their work so that won't be the problem.
The old DOM was the previous content that was in the body

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: Do you set up you event handling for the new DOM after every load? Or do you use `.live` or `.delegate` for adding the event handler?

Comment: There is no event handler, as I told I load the page and I start a foreach.